# Looking for a within app transition (revolving screen effect)

Tags: iphone, transition

I want a transition within my app that is like the mystery revolving wall from old scooby doo cartoons.  I want the screen to revolve when switching views.  Anyone point me in the right direction for the possibility of accomplishing this?

Comment: Really I am just learning the beginnings of app building in the IOS programming guide by the Big Nerd Ranch guys.  Looking forward to seeing if I can implement my app ideas within the existing framework.

Comment: Pretty cool that it is built into XCODE now that I have come back to play some more with IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

//optional if you want to do something after the animation
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myAnimationDidFinish:finished:context:)];
//

[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view2.frame.size.width, view2.frame.size.height)];
[view1 addSubview:view2];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:view1 cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And to flip back:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

//optional if you want to do something after the animation
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myOtherAnimationDidFinish:finished:context:)];
//

[view2 removeFromSuperview];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:view1 cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys.  I am just starting out but I have some wild ideas if I can just learn how to do this stuff.

Comment: No problem. Be sure to accept the best answer that you use, and upvote any helpful answers. You'll get more responses to future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Or this, which uses far less ink:

```
UIView *bookCaseView;    // this is the container... the haunted wall
UIView *booksView;       // just an ordinary set of books, right?
UIView *spookyBackside;  // ruh-roh, raggy!

[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
           duration:0.2
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
           animations:^{
               [booksView removeFromSuperview];
               [bookCaseView addSubview:spookyBackside]; }
           completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Love the Scooby Doo comments :P

Comment: Nice one. +1. My code was from a pre-blocks project. Although blocks may be a bit advanced for a guy with a rep of 1!